# facebookSDK 3.1.1 file not found

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, facebook-ios-sdk, file-not-found

I use XCode 4.5

I downloaded the SDK 3.1.1 from https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.1.1.pkg

and then I import the framework by dragging first and it does not work so I use the method of add other... in the build phases

I have this in my project:

[image]

and this in my build phases:

[image]

but when I import the FacebookSDK library like this

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

I have a file not found:
[image]

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.

Actually the problem was from my Framework Search Paths in the search paths category.

I installed several time the facebook package and import the facebookSDK.framework several times and it adds me the link automatically in my Framework Search Paths.

I just removed all links and recreate a correct one manually and it worked.

Comment: -Go to Build Phases in your Project Target.

    -In Link Binary With Libraries, click the "+" button.

    -Click on "Add Other..." button
    -Browse your FacebookSDK folder. Generally in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/
    -Clik on (select) "facebookSDK.framework" and then OPEN.

Answer (score 0):

if you have facebooksdk.frame work and its not working try this.
Remove frame work, delete it. clear your frame work search paths.
drage FacebookSDK.frame again and update your frame work path if you are working in team.
[image: Relative Path]